# Rise time of a critically damped 2nd order system

Tags: control-system

I am  trying to find the rise time expression of a critically damped 2nd order system.  I am not used to manipulating the inverse Laplace transform and to me it is clearly not easy. It appears that the expression that I found on the internet depends on the value of the damping ratio. The general formula is probably even more complex.

Does anyone know the formula? More generally I am looking for all the time expressions (rise time, settling time, etc.) of a 2nd order system (critically damped, underdamped and overdamped.) I did not find a table on internet summarizing the whole thing.

[image]

Comment: Please define in your picture above what you mean by rise time. Is it \$t_r\$?

Comment: Yes this is it. indeed this is unclear as the picture is looking the rise time between 0% and 100%. I will try to see if I am able to get something from the answer of Rohat Kılıç by resolving non linear equation on python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to compute everything you requested but I'll show you the way:

A second order system has a transfer function in the following form:

$$
T(s)=\frac{C(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+(2\zeta \omega_n)s+\omega_n^2}
$$

where \$C(s)\$ and \$R(s)\$ are output and input, respectively.

For a unit step input i.e. \$R(s)=1/s\$, the output will be:

$$
C(s)=\frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+(2\zeta \omega_n)s+\omega_n^2}
$$

You'll need to take the inverse Laplace transform of the expression above, and you'll get:

$$
c(t)=1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n\ t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}} \ \sin\Bigg(\omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\ t+\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}{\zeta}\Big)\Bigg)
$$

For the sake of simplicity and readability, we can make the following replacements and re-write the expression:

$$
\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}{\zeta}\Big)=\phi \\
\omega_n\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}=\omega_d \\
\Rightarrow c(t)=1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n\ t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}} \ \sin(\omega_d \ t+\phi)
$$

The rest is simple: Make calculations for the following conditions:

- \$\zeta<1\$ i.e. underdamped
- \$\zeta=1\$ i.e. critically damped
- \$\zeta>1\$ i.e. overdamped

<sup>\$\zeta=0\$ i.e. oscillation is out of scope here</sup>

- **Rise time** has different definitions: Generally, it's the time taken by the output to reach 1. But it can be defined as from 10% to 90% for overdamped, and 5% to 95% for critically damped. To calculate rise time, calculate the time-delta for the required conditions by solving for **t** for **c(t)**'s limit values. For example, for underdamped, solve for **t** from \$c(t)=1\$.
- **Settling time** is the time taken by the output to reach its steady value with some error. It's constant for all the types: \$T_s\approx 4/(\zeta\omega_n)\$ for 2% error, and \$T_s\approx 3/(\zeta\omega_n)\$ for 5% error.
- **Peak time** is defined for underdamped response: The time taken by the output to reach its maximum i.e. overshoot. You can solve for **t** from \$dc(t)/dt=0\$ because the tangent at the peak is in parallel with the horizontal axis, so its slope is zero.

**EDIT:** \$\zeta=1\$ is a special condition because the denominator of the second term of \$c(t)\$ goes to infinity. So we should calculate for \$\zeta\rightarrow 1\$ instead (Hello there infinitesimal calculus!):

$$
\lim_{\zeta\rightarrow 1} c(t) = \lim_{\zeta\rightarrow 1} \Bigg(1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n\ t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}} \ \sin(\omega_d \ t+\phi)\Bigg)=1-e^{-\omega_n \ t} (1+\omega_n \ t)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For a system critically damped, it seems to be really hard to resolve the rise time. As the expression when ksi equal 1 does not converge ?

Comment: @Jess sorry, I forgot to mention the special case about \$\zeta = 1\$. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you :) Did you know a book where the demonstration can be extracted ? Or a book on system theory ?

Comment: @Jess sorry, I didn't.